# How to implement zoom on double Click in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, draggable, double-click, scene

How to implement dbl Click on javafx?

I have a scene(with many components) and I want to make it drag able as well as double clickable to zoom in. How can I achieve this dynamic behavior?
I have used the given solution but they are not helpful
When I drag two time then the the double click event get triggers. That I don't want.

A bit of sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: @Adam The problem is mouse released event which is called on both situation. So how to identify in release that it is double clicked released or single clicked release.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the mouse event is a DRAG_DETECTED event before checking for the double click?

Comment: @Miles it seems to work I will update with final code once done.

Comment: @Miles you saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz how it can be duplicate. just becoz it contains dbl click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a wait time, before the drag of the single click gets initiated.

- Boolean that specifies if double click happened
- On drag / drop: set boolean to false
- On drag / drop: wait specified milliseconds before checking the boolean
- On drag / drop: check if boolean false -> proceed
- Double click: set boolean true

That should work?

Edit: On drag / drop: wait specified milliseconds before checking the boolean - That is basically the delay that you define as a double click still being a double click and not two separate clicks

Edit2: Mile's comment to the question seems a better way to go in this case.

Comment: your answer is near to achieve what I want but not completely. the best part is to detect and manage mouse release event based on dragged, clicked and time span between two clicks if its not dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for double click.

```
  myPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                    //Write zooming logic here.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope it will help you.